# Assign IPv4 address to Ubuntu OVA on ESXi

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vmware-esxi

How can I get an IPv4 address for an Ubuntu 1904 VM on ESXI 6.7, deployed from the Ubuntu OVA?

I'm deploying the OVA using `govc`, and I've provided the below spec file. Of note are the `IPProtocol`, `IPAllocationPolicy` and `WaitForIP` fields.

```
{
  "DiskProvisioning": "flat",
  "IPAllocationPolicy": "fixedAllocationPolicy",
  "IPProtocol": "IPv4",
  "WaitForIP": true,
  "PropertyMapping": [
    {
      "Key": "instance-id",
      "Value": "id-ovf"
    },
    ...
```

When the VM comes up, it has an IPv6 local-link address (`fe80::20c:29ff:fe78:c846`), rather than an IPv4 address.

I've tried deploying it with the following `cloud-init` cloud config, to no avail. There are no discernible errors in the `cloud-init` logs. Other elements of the cloud config work fine (such as the writing of `helloworld.json`).

```
#cloud-config

chpasswd:
    list: |
      ubuntu:ubuntu
    expire: false

write_files:
  - content: |
        {
          "say": "helloworld"
        }
    path: /etc/helloworld.json

network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens192:
     dhcp4: no
     addresses: [10.0.0.0/24]
     gateway4: 10.0.0.254
     nameservers:
       addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

I'm trying to stand this VM up as part of an automated process, and want to SSH into it after it booting. I know more about coding than I do about networking, so any help would be most gratefully received.

Comment: Had the same issue, cloud-init is probably superseding your netplan config. Accepted answer here worked for me https://communities.vmware.com/thread/614152

Answer (score 1):

I've not done this myself but it looks to me that for ESXi (which unlike vCenter has no db to store the properties) you need to add the following to your spec file

```
{
...
  "InjectOvfEnv": true,
  "PowerOn": true,
...
```

I found an example of this in Step 6 of https://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2016/04/slick-way-of-deploying-ovfova-directly-to-esxi-vcenter-server-using-govc-cli.html

Comment: Thanks! I'm doing that already actually (it was one of the values I truncated). I'm not sure why the `IPProtocol` isn't being respected, but other values are.